# Upgrade from 3.5 to 4.0, asp Menu hover over not working

Tags: asp.net

I'm attempting up upgrade a web application to from dot net 3.5 to 4.0.

Changed the web.config by adding the controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion and clientIDMode attributes.  That makes them look correct.

```
<pages autoEventWireup="false" theme="MTheme" viewStateEncryptionMode="Always" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
```

However, after that the asp menu hoverover is not working.  I've traced it down to this *eval* function returning nothing.

```
function Menu_GetData(item) {
    if (!item.data) {
        var a = (item.tagName.toLowerCase() == "a" ? item : WebForm_GetElementByTagName(item, "a"));
        var menu = Menu_FindMenu(a);
        try {
            item.data = eval(menu.id + "_Data");
        }
        catch(e) {}
    }
    return item.data;
}
```

In the 3.5 version that evaluated to this value:

```
ctl00_MasterTabs_Data {disappearAfter:500, horizontalOffset:0, verticalOffset:0 }
```

If manually set item.data to have that value in the debugger, the hover menu works.

I tried adding DisappearAfter="500" (where previously there was no value) to the asp:Menu but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the rendered html of asp:menu in ASP.NET 4.0 and ASP.NET 3.5 web application. I suspect item.data is undefined because of some missing data attribute on rendered html.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a result of having a broken 3rd party library (Telerik) that was messing with those attributes.  I upgraded that library and its working.